# Linking A PivotTable filter to a cell

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I know that similar questions have been asked multiple times, but the solutions I have found and adjusted to suit my needs do not seems to work, so I would really appreciate any help.

My issue is that I have a PivotTable2, the filter of which I want to link to a cell value (C1).
The cell value itself is extracted from the slicer connected to another pivot table from a different data source.
I want the filter of a PivotTable2 to be changed automatically when the value in a cell C1 changes.

Here's the macro that I recorded, so it would be probably easier to start with:

```
    Sub Change_Pivot_Table_Filter()

    Range("C59").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("delivery_date"). _
    CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("delivery_date")
    .PivotItems("10/21/2016").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("10/23/2016").Visible = True
    End With
    End Sub
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use worksheet change event and get the result you wanted.
something like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 3 Then
If Target.Value <> "" Then
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("delivery_date").CurrentPage = Target.Value
End If
End If
End Sub
```